# Ansible: Is the any chance of maintain same tag same role but diffrent host name in main yml file by putting any when condition from tasks inside role

Tags: ansible

I have tried to maintain my main yml file like below

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ windows_hostname1 }}"
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
   - Windows
- hosts: "{{ windows_hostname2 }}"
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
   - Windows
```

and my tasks are inside the windows role with same tag name is there any chance of putting when condition to this hosts variable in tasks so I can diffrentiate the execution for two windows hosts.

I have two windows devices which deals differenct tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If tasks of role are not the same, maybe writing 2 roles would be easier. Anyway, you can test the variable `inventory_hostname` in your "when" condition but your role will be stuck with your inventory host names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have tested that condition working fine but when it differe lot hosts it may difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To condition a task based on the host, you can use the `inventory_hostname` which is one of the ["magic" variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables).

**But** then your role will depend on your host names, which is not generic and maintainable.

The best option is to use [group or host variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) and then condition your tasks depending on them, and [organize your hosts in groups via your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups).

And BTW you can merge your plays as they are doing the same (if you want to execute in sequence, you can use the [`serial` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial)).

It would give something like that:

```yaml
# playbook.yml
---
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
   - Windows
```

```yaml
# inventory.yml
---
all:
  children:
    windows:
      children:
        group1:
          hosts:
            host1
        group2:
          hosts:
            host2
```

```yaml
# group_vars/group1.yml
my_var: True
```

```yaml
# group_vars/group2.yml
my_var: False
```

```yaml
# roles/Windows/tasks/main.yml
- name: Do something with condition based on group variable
  [...]
  when: my_var
```

Comment: hey thank you for the detailed explanation.I have followed the same and got that.The only issue we may face if the multiple hostname tasks differ we may need to maintain multiple groups.

Comment: You may need to split your role in multiple roles to apply them independently.